# Angular: How to enable multilingual support in Angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I have an application built with angularJs (version 4). i want to make this app available with two languages (French and English). I checked the official documentation but i'm confused and didn't get how to do it. can any one give the simple steps to translate my app ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngx-translate package is good tool wich can help you achieve what you want. Here is how to do it step by step : 
  **first install ngx-translate :**

```
   npm install @ngx-translate/core --save

   npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

**define your languages files :**
create en.json file and the content should look like this :

```
{
  "TEXT":  "your text  in english here! ", // add many as you need !
}
```

the same for your fr.json file with french translation

**edit your app.module.ts:**

```
    import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from "@ngx-translate/core";
    import {TranslateHttpLoader} from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";

    export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, "i18n/", ".json");
    }
```

in the @NgModule decorator imports add `TranslateModule.forRoot()` 
**use translate pipe:** 
Now you should be able to use the translate pipe in your template just like this :

```
{{ 'TEXT' | translate }}
```

now you need to authorize the user to change language. In order to do that you need to change the component :
add this import : `import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';`
and change the constructor :

```
constructor( private translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.addLangs(["en", "fr"]);
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');

        let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
        translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
    }
```

you add something like this in your html template, to allow the user to change the current langauge :

```
<select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{ lang }}</option>
        </select>
```

Best of luck !

Answer (score 2):

Ng translate will not support in angular2, 
you can use [ngx-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core) in angular2 and 4 web application.
Find the sample configuration and working example in this [plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/WccVZSBM0rUgq2sXSUbe?p=preview)

command to install

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save

npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```